# How to write a customized tokenizer for SQLite in POCO?

Tags: c++, sqlite, poco

I'm working on a full-text search on SQLite which wrapped in Poco library, the default tokenizer (simple, porter, unicode61) failed to meet my requirement so that I have to write a customized tokenizer.

Unfortunately, it was found the POCO didn't provide standard SQLite source code in Poco source and there is no 'ext' or 'fts' folder of files at all.

Does anyone have the experience to extend SQLite in Poco?
Please help, thanks a lot

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Poco merged all definitions of FTS tokenizer into sqlite3.c, so that I have to add my implement into same file unless moving them out.